# What happens to my existing virtual machines when I change the Active Directory for my Azure subscription

Tags: azure, entra-id

I cant find a definative answer on this:

I have an Azure subscription and have some app services and a couple of virtual machines with some iis hosted apps running on them.

I want to try out the new Azure AD B2C.  This will involve [adding a new AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-get-started/) but it needs to be the default for my Azure Subscription.

I see that I can change my AD for my subscription* but I do not know the consequences.  Will it affect my existing Virtual machines, app instances or SQL Databases?

The following shows a screen shot of the SQL Databases tab, but VMs and app servise are the same, where the AD name is shown:

[Example of SQL Databases, showing the AD name, in this case Default Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo75c.png)

*itunity.com/article/how-to-change-the-default-directory-for-an-existing-azure-subscription-2494

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only impact I could imagine is if you have Windows 10 client VMs that are joined to Azure Active Directory. Beyond that, they should continue to operate with zero impact.

Comment: They are server 2012 with local accounts only (I think!)

Should I be using the Azure AD for this?  I wanted to use the B2C for managing external accounts, not the accounts my services etc run under.  Am I looking at this the correct way?

Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry server 2012 RC2 in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Ok - I hit the button and went for it - all seems ok!

Comment: you can't use Azure AD to manage servers. It's meant to auth apps. For now, you need AD on premises. Said that, Azure AD Domain Services is coming (preview atm) which will allow you basic authentication over VMs, but not advanced features like OUs or GPOs.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.  I am playing around with a couple of apps on Azure and different Auth systems.  I didnt want to manage the servers etc, and doubt I will need to.